Can't debug external application. Exception "0x80000004: Single step" when trying to lunch debug
I am making a plugin for the software "TVPaint" and would like to debug it.
The plugin is written in C and C++ and compiled as a .dll, put in the "plugin" folder at the software installation root, and the software automatically detects it and loads it at start.
I have set in the launch.vs.json file, the path of the TVPaint executable as "exe".
When I start debugging, I get the following error.
I also opened in visual studio the TVPaint software installation folder and right clicked in the solution explorer on " TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe " -> selected "Debug", mind this is just the installation folder, without my own code, and it still gives me the Single Step exception.
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TVPaint Developpement\TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits)\TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe'. Module was built without symbols.
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TVPaint Developpement\TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits)\TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe'. Module was built without symbols.
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded without source information.
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded without source information.
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\umpdc.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. 
The thread 23644 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TVPaint Developpement\TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits)\UserMsg.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TVPaint Developpement\TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits)\vcruntime140.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\NapiNSP.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\pnrpnsp.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll'. 
TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlansp_c.dll'. 
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(613)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FF84DFFF6DD: (caller: 00007FF87B70ACF6) LogHr(1) tid(2e78) 8007277C Ce service n’est pas connu. Impossible de trouver le service dans l’espace nom spécifié.
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(613)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FF84DFFF6DD: (caller: 00007FF87B70ACF6) LogHr(2) tid(2e78) 8007277C Ce service n’est pas connu. Impossible de trouver le service dans l’espace nom spécifié.
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(613)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FF84DFFF6DD: (caller: 00007FF87B70ACF6) LogHr(3) tid(2e78) 8007277C Ce service n’est pas connu. Impossible de trouver le service dans l’espace nom spécifié.
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(613)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FF84DFFF6DD: (caller: 00007FF87B70ACF6) LogHr(4) tid(2e78) 8007277C Ce service n’est pas connu. Impossible de trouver le service dans l’espace nom spécifié.
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(613)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FF84DFFF6DD: (caller: 00007FF87B70ACF6) LogHr(5) tid(2e78) 8007277C Ce service n’est pas connu. Impossible de trouver le service dans l’espace nom spécifié.
Exception thrown at 0x00000001410CD885 in TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe: 0x80000004: Single step.
The thread 17572 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 7292 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 11896 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The program '[6620] TVPaint Animation 11.7.1 Pro (64bits).exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).

I looked online and couldn't find any info on this exception and why it might occur.
I also tried to start the debug by selecting "Attach to process..." but a popup window says:
Unable to attach to the process. A debugger is already attached.
It is not my debugger for sure, because even after restarting the computer the result is the same, and none of the affacted files are on a network.
I tried with other apps: Photoshop, Adobe apps, Blender... all of them lauch fine in debug mode in Visual Studio, even if they are protected by a license (none of them is pirated, this is my work computer).
It is just TVPaint that throws the Single Step execption and I am asking for more info on this kind of exception, what causes it, is there a way to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Try adding DebugBreak() at the start of your DLL's DllMain.  Note that some programs "debug" themselves to start an external debugger being attached.

Thank you for your suggerstion. However, I tried it and nothing changed. I also tried other similar solutions, but It might be a bit more complex than that; that's why I was looking for info on the Exception Single Step, so I can try to better understand what's going on with the application.
